# How to activate another standard Theme in "Setup -> Themes and Branding" but via metadata deployment or some api call

Tags: metadata-api, automation, theme-branding

The general goal is to have different theme being set up for sandboxes vs prod org, so that users will not create test data accidently in prod org.

To achieve this, we are trying to script/automate theme selection (Setup -> Themes and Branding). We need to have 'Cloudy Sky' activated for sandboxes instead of 'Lightning Blue' (leaving it for prod org as default).

The question here is how can we switch themes via metadata deployment, api call or whatever. We haven't found so far any other way apart from Web UI.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I see [LightningExperienceTheme](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningexperiencetheme.htm) covered in [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/58). Does it help?

Comment: @Swetha LightningExperienceTheme helps to retrieve/deploy custom theme, but it doesn't return any standard ones, e.g. when doing retrieve with '*' provided as a name. Also there is no option to activate custom theme in this metadata type, e.g. if we decide to clone standard one into custom and activate it instead. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Got your point. I've reached out internally asking if LightningExperienceTheme 
 activation is supported via metadata API.Will let you know as I hear back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve confirmed with concerned Salesforce Product team that currently there is no Metadata or UI API for activating themes. Unfortunately, theme activation is only possible via Web UI.

Please consider logging an Idea on Salesforce [Idea Exchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search) platform to have this functionality implemented.